# Drush on windows xp not working, stuck with no output at all

Tags: drush

I'm having serious trouble running drush from the command line in windows xp.

Php is working fine, and execution of some test scripts work just fine.
When i try to execute drush, both from the folder where the .bat and .php are in, and from any other folder, it seems stuck and show no output or error at all.
I tried changing the batch file to use a specific php.exe instead of relying on PATH variable but nothing changes.

How can i make it work, or at least get some error messages?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: can you execute "drush status"?

Comment: No, it remains silent.
Got one message now, seems like an errore when trying to wget a pear package